# Return List from Query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to return a list from a join query and having difficulty with the errors..

here is my code:

```
public IList<UniStock.Domain.Tables.Inventory> SelectInventoryListByColourSizeGroup(string styleColour, string sizeGroup)
    {
        var db = new UniStockContext();

        IQueryable<Domain.Tables.Inventory> q = (from c in db.Inventories
                   join o in db.SizeGroupSizes
                   on c.Size.Trim() equals o.Description.Trim()
                   where (c.SytleColour == styleColour)
                   && (o.SizeGroup.Description == sizeGroup)
                   select new
                   {
                       c
                   });

        return q;
    }
```

Error I'm seeing now is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: where comes `list` from?

Comment: Sorry I been trying so many ways. list is actually q now.  I will amend question to be corrected.

Comment: In addition, the `q` assignment would not work, because you have a `select new` at the end of the query, which is not the same datatype as `Inventory`.

Comment: How about instead of `select new { c }` put `select c`?

Comment: You have to use `return q.ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your LINQ expression

```
select new { c } ;
```

Will give you a list of **annonymous** type objects. Your method signature says it should return an `IList<Inventory>`. Since you are not returning the expected type, you are getting this compile time error.

You select should be just `c` which is an alias for `db.Inventories` ( with the filter though)

```
var q =  from c in db.Inventories
               join o in db.SizeGroupSizes
                  on c.Size.Trim() equals o.Description.Trim()
                 where (c.SytleColour == styleColour)
                   && (o.SizeGroup.Description == sizeGroup)
               select c;
return q.ToList();
```

The variable `q` will be `IQueryable<Inventory>` and when you call the `ToList()` it will execute the LINQ expression and will get a `List<Inventory>` and you are returning that, which is matching with your method signature (`IList<Signature>`)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, as the error says, you cannot return an anonymous type when your method is expecting a specific type. By using the new {} syntax you are creating an anonymous type. Simply remove new {}

```
public IList<UniStock.Domain.Tables.Inventory> SelectInventoryListByColourSizeGroup(string styleColour, string sizeGroup)
{
    var db = new UniStockContext();

    IQueryable<Domain.Tables.Inventory> q = (from c in db.Inventories
               join o in db.SizeGroupSizes
               on c.Size.Trim() equals o.Description.Trim()
               where (c.SytleColour == styleColour)
               && (o.SizeGroup.Description == sizeGroup)
               select c);

    return q.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! :)

Comment: Where do you define `list`?

Comment: This worked!  I was understanding that part too regarding the types, just unsure on how to get it right in code. Thanks.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, I copied something wrong. Should be return q. I will edit it

Comment: @ninjacoder - still doesn't make sense.  `q` is `IQueryable<>`, not `IList<>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are projecting into a new `AnonymousType` by doing this:

```
select new { c }
```

What you probably want is to select the object itself like this:

```
select c
```

Then you will want to append a `.ToList()` to the end to execute the query and populate the list.